# stanzaio getDiscoInfo failed with timeout

Tags: javascript, xmpp, jitsi, stanza.io

I am trying to connect to the Jabber server of Jitsi using stanza.io.
But this seems more complex than I guess.
Reading the documentation [Reference.md](https://github.com/legastero/stanza.io/blob/master/docs/Reference.md) doesnot helps me to understand the problem.
So I extract a minimal example with getDiscoInfo that raise a timeout.

Using the following code in the stackoverflow snippet failed but fore another reason (access to window.localstorage fails).

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/legastero/stanza.io-demo/gh-pages/stanzaio.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
function write(text) {
    var textNode = document.createElement("li");
    textNode.textContent = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textNode);
}
var serverName = "meet.jit.si";
var userName = "user";  
var roomName = "testroom";
var muc = "conference." + serverName;
var roomUrl = roomName + "@" + muc;

var client = XMPP.createClient({
  jid: roomName + "@" + serverName,
  boshURL: location.protocol+ "//" + serverName + "/http-bind",
  transports: ['bosh']
});

client.connect();                   
client.getDiscoInfo(roomUrl,'', (err, data) => {
    write("err:"+ JSON.stringify(err) + " data:"  + JSON.stringify(data))
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

However this could run from this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpromonet/gy2m06j7).

It fails with error :

> err:{"id":"5d30db9b-b2f1-4915-b387-424cb6e1673a","type":"error","error":{"condition":"timeout"}}
>   data:undefined

I tried with getTime and some others methods.
But some calls are working like

```
client.joinRoom(roomUrl, userName, {status:"available"});
```

As behavior is the same using a local jitsi instance and using the publicly available server meet.jit.si, I guess the problem is not in my installation.

Do you know why nearly all requests to the XMPP server fails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getDiscoItems method need to be called after session initialization.

I was able to get answer modifying the code like this :

```
client.on('session:started', () => {
    client.getDiscoItems(muc,'', (err, data) => {
        write("err:"+ JSON.stringify(err) + " data:"  + JSON.stringify(data))
    });
} )
```

[JSFillde](https://jsfiddle.net/mpromonet/mtuegvdk/)

It give the expected result :

> err:null
>   data:{"discoItems":{},"lang":"en","id":"cc3c40c8-0528-42d0-879c-fb67cf400b92","to":"ad2506f3-03ef-4c7c-b472-bc757070e570@meet.jit.si/2c52a03b-8eb1-4329-8dbe-de68a2c4f682","from":"conference.meet.jit.si","type":"result"}